# input text box width same as parent

Tags: html, css

How can I have a textbox that inherits the width of it's container?

For example I have a div that has a textbox inside it.

```
<div id='content' style='width:100%;'>
    <input type='text' name='txtUsername'>
</div>
```

What I wanted to do is when I resize my browser, the text box must follow the width of it's parent div.

With the code above, the textbox always overflow it's container whenever I resize the browser to a smaller width.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use `box-sizing:border-box` together with `width:100%`.
This way `input` will fit 100% of container's width but will not overflow it because of added `input`'s padding:

```
#content input
{
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Live demo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/745Mt/1/

More information about `box-sizing` CSS property with examples: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

Just add   `style='width:100%;'` (or how much % do you need) to the Input

```
  <div id='content' style='width:100%;'> <input style='width:100%;' type='text' name='txtUsername'> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the width of the input to 100%? e.g.

```
input {width:100%;}
```