# Dynamic input box width in Foundation 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm just getting started with Foundation and trying to create a title bar with a search box. I want the search box to fill all available space in the title bar. However, nothing I've tried has quite worked:

1) I tried setting a 50% width but at small screen sizes it pushed the other buttons off the top row

2) I tried to implement this solution but couldn't get it working (see commented css)
[Dynamic width for input text box (HTML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092074/dynamic-width-for-input-text-box-html)

I've set up a jsfiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/B7nS8/1/

Thanks for your help!

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="lt-ie10" lang="en" > <![endif]-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My Site</title>


    <meta name="description" content="Desc." />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://foundation.zurb.com/assets/css/templates/foundation.css" />
    <script src="http://foundation.zurb.com/assets/js/modernizr.js"></script>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

        .row { max-width: 1200px; }

/*      .searchParent div { overflow: hidden; }
        .searchText { width: 100%;  }
        .searchButton { float: right; }
*/
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->

    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
        <ul class="title-area">
            <!-- Title Area -->
            <li class="name">
                <h1>
                    <a href="#">
                        My Site
                    </a>
                </h1>
            </li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <form>
                <ul class="left">
                    <li class="has-form"> 
                        <div class="row collapse searchParent"> 
                            <div class="large-8 small-9 columns searchText"> 
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Find Stuff"> 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="large-4 small-3 columns searchButton"> 
                                <a href="#" class="button expand">Search</a> 
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>

            <ul class="right">
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </nav>

    <!-- End Top Bar -->

    <div class="row">
        <div class="large-12 columns">

            <div class="row">



            </div><!-- End Thumbnails -->

        </div>
    </div>

<!-- End Content -->


<!-- Footer -->

<footer class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns"><hr>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="large-6 columns">
                <p>&copy; Copyright no one at all. Go to town.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="large-6 small-12 columns">
                <ul class="inline-list right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

    <!-- End Footer -->


<script>
    document.write('<script src=js/vendor/' +
        ('__proto__' in {} ? 'zepto' : 'jquery') +
        '.js><\/script>')
</script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
<!-- End Footer -->
<script src="http://foundation.zurb.com/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://foundation.zurb.com/assets/js/templates/foundation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look at foundations docs for [topbar.js](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html) and [form inputs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/forms.html), they're easy to follow and have given examples which do almost exactly what you are trying to do.

You shouldn't really need to write any css, that's what foundations is for.

I'd suggest something like this:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar=""> 

   <!-- Title -->
   <ul class="title-area">

    <!-- Mobile Menu Toggle -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
   </ul>

   <!-- Top Bar Section -->

   <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <div class="row collapse">
          <div class="small-10 columns">
           <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
        <div class="small-2 columns"> <a href="#" class="button postfix">Go</a> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

Make sure you also remember to include a reference to `topbar.js` after `foundation.min.js`

**Edit: Added an alternate approach**

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="">
  <ul class="title-area" style="width: 100%">
    <li class="name has-form">
        <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-11 columns"> 
            <input type="text" placeholder="Find Stuff"> 
        </div>      
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href=""><span></span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work, putting a row in the top bar seemed to break things - http://jsfiddle.net/ZjHQh/2 or http://jsfiddle.net/ZjHQh/3/

Comment: I tidied up the fiddle a bit here: http://jsfiddle.net/ghn28/4/ it gives you a pretty good place to start for the positioning (be sure to remove inline css if you use this).