# Dynamic width textbox

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find a way to make a textbox input control have a dynamic width in so much as I want it to collapse around it's content/ grow with it's content, like a div.

I've tried display:inline... tried fiddling with min-width and max-width... read various posts such as [Dynamic width for input text box (HTML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092074/dynamic-width-for-input-text-box-html) but can't get it working...

I want it to look like this, but I want it dynamically sizing it's width, I can't hard code the width (notice the lack of space between 9999.99 and the word tonnes):

```
<div style="width:420px;background-color:red">
    Gross Weight Unit:
    <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    Total Gross Weight: <input style="border:0;background:transparent;width:50px" type="text" name="lname" value="9999.99"> tonnes
</div>
```

display:inline doesn't work (notice the space between 9999.99 and the word tonnes, it's too big):

```
<div style="width:420px;background-color:red">
    Gross Weight Unit:
    <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    Total Gross Weight: <input style="border:0;background:transparent;display:inline" type="text" name="lname" value="9999.99"> tonnes
</div>
```

max-width doesn't give the desired effect, it simply grows to 100px regardless of it's content (notice the space between 9999.99 and the word tonnes, it's too big):

```
<div style="width:420px;background-color:red">
      Gross Weight Unit:
    <select>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    Total Gross Weight: <input style="border:0;background:transparent;max-width:100px" type="text" name="lname" value="9999.99"> tonnes
</div>
```

Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I think this JavaScript library might help http://kamilkp.github.io/autoheight/

Comment: Throwing a javascript library at a problem that possibly could be solved with  CSS is ill-advised.  Best to determine what the problem is first.

Comment: @orangeh0g I didn't find any CSS only solution of given problem, would appreciate if you can help. Definitely it's worse to add a JS dependency if the problem can be solved with only CSS.